# Fail2Ban how to match any string

Tags: fail2ban

I have a very simple situation but I can't figure out how regex works...
I have an application generating a log only when a login problem occurs. So there is no line in log except in case of wrong login or in case of attempt to reset a password too many times. So potentially, I don't even need to search a particular string in log, any entry matches. Here is a log example :

```
2019-10-20 18:44:35 127.0.0.1 login.php : Authentication error - account not initialized : client XXXX, login YYYY
2019-10-20 21:31:17 127.0.0.1 login.php : Authentication error - password error : client XXXX, login XXXX
2019-10-20 21:29:39 127.0.0.1 login.php : Authentication error - client contains wrong chars : client XXXX, login YYYY 
2019-10-21 06:25:25 127.0.0.1 login.php : Authentication error - account locked : client XXXX, login YYYY
2019-10-21 06:48:11 127.0.0.1 user.php : Authentication - Unlocking : client XXXX, login YYYYY
```

I have a problem with regular expression cause I can't understand how it works (for years). All I tried give me errors when I start fail2ban : Unable to compile regular expression,  No failure-id group in 'Authentication error', ... Damned, it looks so easy !

Answer (score 2):

Finally...

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = <HOST> .* Authentication
```

Please note this works but I found without understand anything. If someone has a link where how fail2ban works is explained. I found many but none of them have clear explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick is the fact that `error.log` files look different from tutorials and you need to rewrite *failregex* manually. Another trick is that `<HOST>` is a [predefined regexp](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters) that tries to match an `ip` but it could match something like datetime instead
In such case like

```
[Tue Nov 08 03:03:03.349852] bla-bla [client 1.2.3.4:5] bla-bla xxx bla-bla
```

In case you're banning when *xxx* appear

```
[Definition]
failregex = client <HOST>(.*)xxx
```

Sadly quick google search upon `fail2ban` and tutorials indeed explain little. I also wanted to ban by simple string match.